# JSF Repeat nog showing value in checkbox

Tags: java, jsf

I'm passing a hashmap which consists out of an object + a boolean into my view and I want to display the value of the boolean of each object and currently have the following code:

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{userTypeController.permissionItems}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userTypeController.checkMap[item]}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
```

And the Hashmap method:

```
    public Map<Permission, Boolean> getCheckMap() {
    checkMap = null;
    for (Permission p : getPermissionItems()) {
        if (getPermissionItemsUserType().contains(p))
            checkMap.put(p, Boolean.TRUE);
        else
            checkMap.put(p, Boolean.FALSE);
        System.out.println(checkMap.get(p).toString());
    }
    return checkMap;
}
```

This should work and during the system.out.println I see a true output...

However, the checkboxes itself are never checked... Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms which you describe matches [Mojarra bug 1807](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1807) which was by coincidence fixed in 2.1.1 and was officially fixed in 2.1.4. So, [upgrading](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) Mojarra to at least 2.1.1 should do.

Note that you've a major bug in your code. You are nowhere instantiating the `checkmap`, it would throw a `NullPointerException`, although this seems to be oversimplifying of the code for the question. Also, doing this inside a getter is a bad idea. It should be done during the (post)construct or an event listener method. A getter can be called more than once during render response. See also [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062).

Comment: Upgraded to 2.1.4, still have the same issue... Anything else I could try?

Comment: Well, don't do the logic in the getter, but in the (post)constructor or whatever method which is called only once long before render response phase. Otherwise, a valid SSCCE would be helpful as yours contains bugs.